# White color in the bottom of Layout

Tags: android

I am unable to understand why white color is showing in the bottom of layout.
I am using view pager containing various pages.Layout contain layout background image and two text view. Problem is that white color is showing on some pages.

My Layout

```
    <Relative Layout 
    android:id="@+id/layouts"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >

    <Scroll View
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >

    <Linear Layout 
    android:id="@+id/images"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >


    <Text View
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />



    <Text View
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    />

    </Linear Layout>
    </Scroll View>
    </Relative Layout>
```

XML for view pager Declaration

```
        <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout                          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mypager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!-- The main content view -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/content_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
<!-- The navigation drawer -->

   <ListView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_list"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="#111"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="#FFCC00"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />

       </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Show xml for view pager declaration. Also upload screenshot of screen which shows white color.

Comment: first thing you should do is that you should do proper formatting with your view, its a messy view ... use ctrl + shift + f if you are using windows

Comment: Xml for view pager declaration added

Comment: Can you post a screen shot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `ScrollView`'s [`fillViewPort`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android:fillViewport) attribute to `true` to make it fill all vertical space on screen in case the scroll view content itself doesn't use it all.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably the scroll view height being set to wrap content.

So if the content is smaller than the screen height the scroll View is too, leaving a gap at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: now I set scroll view height match_parent. but problem is still same